exam with answer space in parts with letter at start
I'd like the question to call for an answer with two parts in it. To remind candidates, I'd like the (a) and (b) to appear left and in line with their set of lines.
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[2] Name any two vegetables.
\begin{parts}
\part
\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
\part
\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}


It seems that \part expect you write a question before \fillwithdottedlines.
A workaround is to begin an empty paragraph, for example with \noindent, and remove the extra space with \vspace{-\dottedlinefillheight}. That is :
\part \noindent\vspace{-\dottedlinefillheight}
\fillwithdottedlines{2cm}

Example:
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[2] Name any two vegetables.
\begin{parts}
  \part \noindent\vspace{-\dottedlinefillheight}
  \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
  
  \part \noindent\vspace{-\dottedlinefillheight}
  \fillwithdottedlines{2cm}
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}



Thank you very much
